# Git cross-compatibility issues with line changes

Tags: git

I am working on a project and compiling on a remote Linux machine with Git installed on it. My working environment is Windows, and I have access to the Linux folder from my machine Windows with samba. I've been careful to edit all my files using LF as line endings (even on Windows). Still, when I type `git status` on the remote Linux machine, it shows -as expected- the filed I modified, but on Windows it shows way too much files, some of which I'm sure I never touched.

I tried using `core.autocrlf = false` and `core.eol = lf` on my Windows Git config, but that does not change anything.

Edit : forgot this.
I did a `git diff`. No changes were found. That's why I suspect line ending issues.
I even git a `git reset --hard` from the Windows console, only to find that it did not change anything : the same files were shown as modified

Comment: did you `git diff you/file` to make sure that's what git thinks changed?

Comment: I did. No changes were found. That's why I suspect line ending issues. 
I even git a ```git reset --hard``` from the Windows console, only to find that it did not change anything : the same files were shown as modified (putting that into my original topic)

Comment: *and I have access to the Linux folder from my machine Windows with samba* - does this mean you're working directly on a shared file system containing the `.git` directory? If so, *stop doing that*, it doesn't work well.

Comment: @torek that's exactly what I'm doing, and I don't have a lot of other options unfortunately. Any way I can solve the problem ?

Comment: Only some seriously ugly ones using the GIT_INDEX_FILE variable. The problem is that `stat` data in Windows won't match that in Linux and vice versa, so that `.git/index` always looks "wrong" to the foreign system. If the `.git` directory is network-mounted with different systems accessing it, you get this behavior.